# Anagram algorithm objective C

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, anagram

i have written the following code to check anagram want to know is this perfect & is there any better way to implement the same in objective C

```
-(BOOL) findAnagram :(NSString *) string1 :(NSString *) string2
{
    int len = string1.length;
    if (len != string2.length)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i=0; i < len; i++)
    {
        int h = 0;
        int q = 0;
        for (int k = 0;  k < len ; k ++)
        {
            if ([string1 characterAtIndex:i] == [string1 characterAtIndex:k])
            {
                h++;
            }
            if ([string1 characterAtIndex:i] == [string2 characterAtIndex:k])
            {
                q++;
            }
        }

        if (h!=q)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: This should be on the Code Review site.

Comment: This question belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 23):

A better performing version than yours, which is a O(n ^ 2) algorithm, is a O(n) algorithm:

```
BOOL anagrams(NSString *a, NSString *b)
{
    if (a.length != b.length)
        return NO;

    NSCountedSet *aSet = [[NSCountedSet alloc] init];
    NSCountedSet *bSet = [[NSCountedSet alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        [aSet addObject:@([a characterAtIndex:i])];
        [bSet addObject:@([b characterAtIndex:i])];
    }

    return [aSet isEqual:bSet];
}
```

Comment: +1 for `NSCountedSet`. Too many people have no idea that this class even exists and what it can be used for (and then use `NSDictionary` and `NSNumber`... ugh)

Comment: You also need to lowercase, and drop non letters. Something like `a = [[[a componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""] lowercaseString];`. Example anagram for testing: “Tom Marvolo Riddle”, “I am Lord Voldemort”.

Comment: @Jano true, but I assumed that that particular detail was already implemented by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You want to know if two strings contain exactly the same characters? Easiest way would probably be to sort both of them and compare the sorted version.

Another way would be to count the number of appearances of each letter (how many As, how many Bs, and so forth), then compare those counts.

(Note: The second way is just a variation of the first one, it's one efficient way to sort a string)

Comment: His algorithm is doing exactly your second idea, although it checks twice, or three times, etc, if there's more than 1 occurrence of a certain character.

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine to me. But the code style is slightly odd. I would write it like this:

```
- (BOOL)isStringAnagram:(NSString *)string1 ofString:(NSString *)string2 {
    int len = string1.length;
    if (len != string2.length) {
        return NO;
    }

    for (int i=0; i < len; i++) {
        int h = 0;
        int q = 0;
        for (int k = 0;  k < len; k++) {
            if ([string1 characterAtIndex:i] == [string1 characterAtIndex:k]) {
                h++;
            }
            if ([string1 characterAtIndex:i] == [string2 characterAtIndex:k]) {
                q++;
            }
        }

        if (h != q) {
            return NO;
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

The main issue I have is with the method name. While it's possible to have parameters that have nothing before them in the name, it is not advisable. i.e. you had `findAnagram::` as the name whereas I've used `isStringAnagram:ofString:`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following method which check Anagram strings.

```
-(BOOL)checkAnagramString:(NSString*)string1 WithAnotherString:(NSString*)string2{

  NSCountedSet *countSet1=[[NSCountedSet alloc]init];
  NSCountedSet *countSet2=[[NSCountedSet alloc]init];

  if (string1.length!=string2.length) {
    NSLog(@"NOT ANAGRAM String");
    return NO;
  }


  for (int i=0; i<string1.length; i++) {
      [countSet1 addObject:@([string1 characterAtIndex:i])];
      [countSet2 addObject:@([string2 characterAtIndex:i])];
  }

  if ([countSet1 isEqual:countSet2]) {
    NSLog(@"ANAGRAM String");
    return YES;
  } else {
    NSLog(@"NOT ANAGRAM String");
    return NO;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an implementation on @zmbq suggestion of sorting and comparing.

You should consider the requirements of deleting spaces and being case insensitive.

```
- (BOOL)isAnagram:(NSString *)leftString and:(NSString *)rightString {
  NSString *trimmedLeft = [[leftString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""] lowercaseString];
  NSString *trimmedRight = [[rightString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""] lowercaseString];
  return [[self stringToCharArraySorted:trimmedLeft] isEqual:[self stringToCharArraySorted:trimmedRight]];
}

- (NSArray *)stringToCharArraySorted:(NSString *)string {
  NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  for (int i = 0 ; i < string.length ; i++) {
    [array addObject:@([string characterAtIndex:i])];
  }
  return [[array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)] copy];
}
```

called like this

```
BOOL isAnagram = [self isAnagram:@"A BC" and:@"cba"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Another run of the mill algorithm:

```
- (BOOL) testForAnagramWithStrings:(NSString *)stringA andStringB: (NSString *)stringB{

    stringA = [stringA lowercaseString];

     stringB = [stringB lowercaseString];


     int counter = 0;

     for (int i=0; i< stringA.length; i++){


         for (int j=0; j<stringB.length;j++){


             if ([stringA characterAtIndex:i]==[stringB characterAtIndex:j]){

                 counter++;

             }


         }

     }

     if (counter!= stringA.length){

         return false;
     }

     return true;

}
```